# Bad contrast with simple-scan and Canon TR4550

Tags: canon, sane

Ubuntu 20.04 - libsane-common 1.0.32+git20210215-focal0

Hi,
I finally got my Canon TR4550 scanner (wifi mode) to be correctly detected editing `/etc/sane.d/escl.conf` file, and adding a new device line like below :

```
device https://192.168.1.29:443 "Canon TR4550 Serie"
```

But the contrast is not correct using simple-scan, scanned documents background is greyed, while contrast is good when using windows VM and Canon SW, see below :

[image: ubuntu and windows comparison]

Using Quality Parameters (Contrast/Brightness) has no effect.

So I suppose this is a bug, but I do not know where to create it : Ubuntu or Sane ? Can somebody tell me how to proceed ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I created a [defect on sane-project backend GitLab](https://gitlab.com/sane-project/backends/-/issues/451) : it appears it is not a bug, the TR4550 scanner does not expose contrast. Simple-scan does not provide a software layer to do this work.
Workaround to the issue :
Use the xsane software which allows you to do this work.